# add blankspace to xml file using yattag Python

Tags: python, special-characters, yattag

I would like to add a blankspace as value between tags.

```
with tag('Value'):
    text(" ")
```

And I expected to have this:

```
<Value> </Value>
```

Though I get this:

```
<Value></Value>
```

I've tried a few attempts, such as using char codes or getting [1] of a "a a" string, but whenever it is just a blankspace, it adds no value in the xml file

Comment: I just tried your code and I get the expected result (with a space). Are you using the indent function?

Comment: I am. by the end of all tags I have standard:

Comment: indent(
    doc.getvalue(),
    indentation = ' '*4,
    newline = '\n'
    )

Comment: try like this: ``indent(doc.getvalue(), blank_is_text=True, indentation=' '*4, newline='\n')``

Comment: Okay... i've tried it without indent and indeed, expected result. Though, how to have a nice file with that blankspace in there?